# Jquery not loading on normal refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript and Jquery is not loading on normal page refresh, but loads correctly on hard refresh (CTRL+SHIFT+R) and Incognito.

I'm calling the functions through window.onload:

```
window.onload = function() { 
   adddata(); adddata_pages(); 
   adddata_views7(); 
   adddata_pages7(); 
   adddata_views1(); 
   adddata_pages1(); 
};
```

And I'm including the Jquery files in this order in the head of html:
**jquery.min.js , bootstrap.min.js , Chart.min.js , jquery.dataTables.js**.

And in the end (before closing body tag) I'm calling my external js file which has all my functional code.

Can please anyone help as where I'm going wrong or what is the solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Load your external js file inside document ready tags. jQuery has to be first in load order.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //load here your file
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on your IDE in NetBeans you should refresh the cache to see the changes. Because refreshing page is not helping at all.Alternative solution is that you could use nodejs which uses auto refreshing when typing.